# Array Range and IsEmpty If Then Statement VBA. Overwrites everything instead of selectively inserting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm brand new to VBA.  Got about 4 weeks under my belt so far. And this is the last portion of a long list of macros for completing data cleanup and analysis for a report. Maybe this isn't the best way to do this? I'm still new to this, so I'm open to other suggestions. But it needs to be a macro. This is basically what it looks like (the highlighted fields are filled with a vlookup, which is why I have two different arrays because they're not contiguous):

[link to snip of the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dihp.jpg)

The number of rows varies depending on the report. Sometimes its 4000 rows, sometimes its more, sometimes its less. But I've made sure that every column would be the same. We're trying to automate as much of it as we can so that we might be able to get some less-technical people to be able to run through the entire process. The first time I went through the process it took me 6 hours (although I was taking notes too).   For the senior person here it takes about 2 hours for each one, depending. We have somewhere around 300 of these to do before the end of the year.

Anyways, this code works, but it overwrites all of my iferror/vlookup results that I inserted.  I'm guessing my 'For Each If Then' statement is to blame.  But I've been working on this for a couple days, trying different ways to achieve this goal and this is closest that I've gotten.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure its something super simple...

```
Sub AutomateAllTheThings6()
Dim arr3() As String
Dim arr11() As String
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng11 As Range
Dim sourcerng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
    Call OptimizeCode_Begin
        lastRow = Range("D1:D" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row).Rows.Count
        Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ2" & ":BH" & lastRow)
        Set rng11 = ActiveSheet.Range("BL2:BV2" & ":BL" & lastRow)
        Set sourcerng = ActiveSheet.Range("BE2:BF2" & ":BE" & lastRow)
        arr3() = Split("UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN", ",")
        arr11() = Split("UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, NEEDS REVIEW", ",")
            For Each cell In sourcerng
                If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    rng3.Value = arr3
                    rng11.Value = arr11
                End If
            Next
    Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

Comment: your ranges are wrong: `Range("BH2:BJ2" & ":BH" & lastRow)` should by `Range("BH2:BJ" & lastRow)` etc.

Comment: 1. Read all of @Scott Craner's comments 2. Turn them into answers 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: For example:  if you press Ctrl +G and enter the following in the immedate window: debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ2" & ":BH" & 3).Address
you get $BH$2:$BJ$3, this is an example substituting 3 for lastRow but shows what is actually happening

Comment: @QHarr That may be correct but it is still poor practice as it force vba to do one more step in parsing the string to make it a valid range.

Comment: @ScottCraner Not promoting the practice just thought it might help the OP visualize what is actually happening.  Why i upvoted your initial comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are refering to the whole range with:

> `rng3.Value = arr3`

So when any are found blank the whole range gets set, not just that row.  We can do just that row by using `Intersect`

```
Intersect(rng3, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = arr3
```

Also, Your ranges are in error

> `Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ2" & ":BH" & lastRow)`

would refer to range `BH2:BJ2:BH100`

Cahnge to:

```
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ" & lastRow)
```

so:

```
Sub AutomateAllTheThings6()
Dim arr3() As String
Dim arr11() As String
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng11 As Range
Dim sourcerng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
    Call OptimizeCode_Begin
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
        Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ" & lastRow)
        Set rng11 = ActiveSheet.Range("BL2:BV" & lastRow)
        Set sourcerng = ActiveSheet.Range("BE2:BF" & lastRow)
        arr3() = Split("UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN", ",")
        arr11() = Split("UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, NEEDS REVIEW", ",")
            For Each cell In sourcerng
                If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    Intersect(rng3, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = arr3
                    Intersect(rng11, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = arr11
                End If
            Next
    Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott!  Like, for real.  This has been frustrating me for the past couple of days.  If you're ever in Portland the first round is on me!

Comment: @pnwAnalyst Oregon or Maine?

Comment: Portland, Oregon :)

Comment: Ah... god's country, born and raised on the east side, {Go, Lancers}.  Moved for work.  @pnwAnalyst

Comment: I would add `Exit For` after `Intersect` statements. There are 2 cells to be checked for emptiness, so if both are empty, the same data is pasted twice.  Also I would replace `Intersect(rng3, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value` with just `rng3.Rows(cell.Row)`.

Comment: If you exit the for and there are other blanks in other rows then it will not put the necessary data in those rows.  And yes the `rng3.rows(cell.Row)` is another way to do it.  I prefer intersect. @RyszardJędraszyk

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had my head still on my code where there are 2 loops: for rows and columns, so `Exit For` is no good there, also the `cell.Row` which I mentioned would need to be adjusted by first row of the range, so it's not that straightforward.

Comment: @ScottCraner If you have some time Scott, I think I might need your help again. I figured that after I got the arrays situated that filling in the remaining fields would be easy. Namely columns BE, BG and BK. Here's my snip again. I don't care about column BF
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dihp.jpg

Column BE copy from column Z unless Z=0, then copy from column O.

Column BG copy from column AA, unless AA="Unknown" then copy from column I.

Column BK copy from column AB, unless AB="Unkown" then copy from column N.

Comment: I wrote an IIF statement for them, but I couldn't get it to work for....more than one column.

Comment: New problems get new questions.  Please ask a new question, you can refer to this one.  Show how you tried to modify it and where you are stuck.

Comment: Cool.  Will do.  I didn't want to clog things up by starting a new thread but will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use such version with arrays. Although in my code results are not pasted into arrays, the computing is done based on them, what makes code execute much faster than when operating on cells in range.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub AutomateAllTheThings6()

Dim arr3() As String, arr11() As String
Dim rng3 As Range, rng11 As Range, sourceRng As Range
Dim vSource As Variant
Dim nCounter1 As Long, nCounter2 As Long, lastRow As Long

    Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    Const firstRow As Long = 2

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("D1:D" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row).Rows.Count
        Set rng3 = .Range("BH" & firstRow & ":BJ" & lastRow)
        Set rng11 = .Range("BL" & firstRow & ":BV" & lastRow)
        Set sourceRng = .Range("BE" & firstRow & ":BF" & lastRow)
    End With

    vSource = sourceRng

    arr3() = Split("UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN", ",")
    arr11() = Split("UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, 00/00/0000, NEEDS REVIEW", ",")

    For nCounter1 = LBound(vSource) To UBound(vSource) 'loop through all rows in source range
        For nCounter2 = LBound(vSource, 2) To UBound(vSource, 2) 'loop through all columns in the row
            If IsEmpty(vSource(nCounter1, nCounter2)) Then 'if cell is empty
                rng3.Rows(nCounter1) = arr3
                rng11.Rows(nCounter1) = arr11
                Exit For
            End If
        Next nCounter2
    Next nCounter1

   Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I'll save trying to understand this one for my second month of VBA experience.  ;)

lol.  I follow it until the For statements.  Trying to get code to work and learning at the same time makes my head hurt.

Comment: It's quite easy actually, `LBound(vSource)` is lower boundary, array counterpart of first row, `UBound(vSource)` is an upper boundary, a counterpart of last row. `LBound(vSource, 2)` has "2" after comma, what means 2nd dimension: columns. `vSource(nCounter1, nCounter2)` is an array "cell", specified by its "row" and "column" index.

Comment: Also `Option Base 1` changes default `LBound` from 0 to 1 (and as effect increases `Ubound by 1`), I most often use it, so that arrays have the same enumeration as rows and columns on sheet.