# How To Have VBA Insert Formula Result as a Value

Tags: vba, excel

[I got help last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231508/array-range-and-isempty-if-then-statement-vba-overwrites-everything-instead-of) getting my syntax and ranges correct, and thought I could just do a `vlookup` to finish it but apparently I was mistaken.  It just seems like when I try to research how to accomplish this, I find various examples but I don't have the background to translate it to my code.

The macro runs and does *almost* everything its supposed to do.  But in addition to inserting the arrays, there are 3 other cells that need values when there are blank cells in my ‘sourcerng’.

[image: Snip of my worksheet]

This is the logic for the cells that need values (the values are already in my worksheet, I just need to get them to these blank cells).  I tried to do an IIF statement for these but I still have no idea what I'm doing.  Would that be the best way? Should it just be another IF THEN statement?

**rngBE**   - IF Column Z = 0 Then copy value from corresponding row in column O.  Otherwise copy value from column Z

**rngBG**   - IF Column AA = "Unknown" Then copy value from corresponding row in column I.  Otherwise copy value from column AA.

**rngBK**   - IF Column AB = "Unknown" Then copy value from corresponding row in column N.  Otherwise copy value from column AB.

```
Sub AutomateAllTheThings6()
Dim arr3() As String
Dim arr11() As String
'Dim resBE As String
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng11 As Range
Dim rngBE As Range
Dim rngBG As Range
Dim rngBK As Range
Dim sourcerng As Range
'Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
'Dim i As Long

    Call OptimizeCode_Begin
        'firstRow = 2
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
        Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("BH2:BJ" & lastRow)
        Set rng11 = ActiveSheet.Range("BL2:BV" & lastRow)
        Set rngBE = ActiveSheet.Range("BE2:BE" & lastRow)
        Set rngBG = ActiveSheet.Range("BG2:BG" & lastRow)
        Set rngBK = ActiveSheet.Range("BK2:BK" & lastRow)
        Set sourcerng = ActiveSheet.Range("BE2:BE" & lastRow)
        arr3() = Split("UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN", ",")
        arr11() = Split("UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,00/00/0000, _
                         00/00/0000,00/00/0000,00/00/0000,NEEDS REVIEW", ",")
            For Each cell In sourcerng
                If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    Intersect(rng3, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = arr3
                    Intersect(rng11, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = arr11
                    '***PLS HELP***
                    Intersect(rngBE, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = "WEEEEE"
                    Intersect(rngBG, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = "WOOOOO"
                    Intersect(rngBK, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = "WAAAAA"
                End If
            Next
        Range("BR2:BU2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Columns("BF:BF").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub


'*********TESTING***********
'resBE      = IIf(Cells(13,Z).Value = 0, Cells(13,BE).Value = Cells(13,Z), Cells(13,BE).Value = Cells(13,O)) 

'***************************************
'For i = firstRow To lastRow
'           valZ = Range("Z" & i)
'           valOh = Range("O" & i)
'           
'           If valZ = 0 Then
'               rngBE.Value = valOh
'               Else rngBE.Value = valZ
'           End If
```

Comment: For Range BE, can you just have an incell formula?
=if(Z2=0,O2,Z2)

Comment: I'm really trying to keep this as "automated" as I can, because other "non-technical" people will eventually be running this.  I did try that initially when I got stumped but I can't fill down the formula because the rows with blank cells are interspersed randomly. With the test data that I'm using there are 4k rows, but only 300ish rows where this would apply.

Comment: For VBA you can us the range().formula = "=if(Z2=0,O2,Z2)", putting in the correct row numbers, of course.  Or you can make the range().value = to the result of the =if(Z2=0,O2,Z2) logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do your task. If you're more of an "Excel" person than VBA you might consider this approach: You can inject the syntax of any "regular" formula in R1C1 Format.

So the formula mentioned above `=if($Z2=0,$O2,$Z2)` is `.FORMULA` format for any value in row 2.
But in `.FORMULAR1C1` it can be inserted in ANY cell as: `=IF(RC26=0,RC15,RC26)` (basically no rows up or down, but always columns O (15) and Z(26).

So, your modified code would have something like this:

```
Intersect(rngBE, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC26=0,RC15,RC26)"
Intersect(rngBE, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value = _ 
Intersect(rngBE, ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row)).Value
```

Again, this is NOT the most efficient way to accomplish your task, but if you're dealing with thousandsof rows, versus tens to hundreds of thousands, I wouldn't worry about it and it gives you a new tool to use.

Comment: So I'm really more of a SQL guy.  But that is definitely exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

And yeah I haven't seen a report that had more than 9k rows.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to change title of post to be more open-ended as your overall problem is how to get a conditional statement to be evaluated versus anything related to isempty function. I might suggest, "How To Have VBA Insert Formula Result as a Value". Just an idea to make a more useful contribution to community. Regardless, glad it worked and thanks for the check.